# How to create a custom color picker dialog or popup screen in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry

How to create a custom color picker dialog or popup screen in BlackBerry
(i.e selecting the color form color picker dialog to set any control or other mnger)

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea of a possible implementation:

It should be a `PopupScreen` that holds a `GridFieldManager` containing a set of small custom fields (e.g. a 8x8 matrix). Each small custom field is painted in its color and "listens" for clicks in its `navigationClick()`. When a click is caught by small custom field it notifies the screen about the selected color. The screen closes itself and notifies the client/caller via some callback passed to the screen on its creation.